# Можно ли упростить данный метод InputBigDecimal java

Tags: java

Хочу упросить данный метод, но не знаю как. Если есть варианты, то буду рад увидеть.

```
public BigDecimal InputBigDecimal()
     {
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            BigDecimal number= new BigDecimal("0.0");
            boolean proverka=true;
            while(proverka)
            {
                if(sc.hasNextBigDecimal())
                {
                    number=sc.nextBigDecimal();
                    if(number.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) <= 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter correctly number>0:");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                        proverka=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter correctly number;");
                    sc.next();
                }
            }
            return number;
        }
```

Comment: public BigDecimal inputBigDecimal() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter correctly number>0:");
            if (sc.hasNextBigDecimal()) {
                BigDecimal number = sc.nextBigDecimal();
                if (number.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) return number;
            } else sc.next();
        }        
    }

Comment: @Дмитрий, спасибо, я совсем забыл про return из цикла!